# General solution of $\cos (2\arctan x) = \frac{{1 - x^2 }}{{1 + x^2 }}?$

Tags: trigonometry

> How to find the general solution of $$\cos (2\arctan x) = \frac{{1 - x^2 }}{{1 + x^2 }}$$

Comment: Do you mean $$\cos (2\arctan x) = \frac{{1 - x^2 }}{{1 + x^2 }}?
$$ Why are you interested in this equation? What do you mean by general solution? This equality holds for all real $x$.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you understand? What are you confused about? These are all important things to include in a good question

Answer (score 1):

$t=\arctan x\iff \tan t=x$.

Recall that $1+x^2=1+\tan^2 t=\frac{1}{\cos^2 t}$, so $\cos^2 t=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Now, $$\cos(2\arctan x)=\cos 2t=\cos^2t-\sin^2t=2\cos^2t-1=2\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1=\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$$ and it is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

If $t=\arctan x$ then $\cos(2t)=2\cos^2t-1=\tfrac{2}{1+x^2}-1=\tfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by substituting both sides into $\arccos()$ function:
$$\arccos(\cos(2 \arctan x)) = \arccos\Biggl(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\Biggl)$$ $$2 \arctan x =\arccos\Biggl(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\Biggl)$$
Then you can take the derivative of both sides: $$\begin{align} \ \frac{2}{1+x^2} &=\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\Biggl(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\Biggl)^2}} \frac{4x}{(1+x^2)^2} \\
&=\ \sqrt{\frac{(1+x^2)^2}{4x^2}} \frac{4x}{(1+x^2)^2} \\ \end{align}$$
If you organize the right-hand side of the equation, you eventually get:
$$\bbox[yellow] {\frac{2}{1+x^2}=\frac{2}{1+x^2}}$$
This means the equation holds for all real $x$ values.